# C# map nested computed properties with AutoMapper

Tags: c#, entity-framework, automapper, dto, computed-properties

I have two basic entities - Invoice and Items for those invoices. This is the basic structure of my entities:

```
public class InvoiceItem
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public decimal Total { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public decimal Price{ get; set; }
    public Enum Type { get; set; }
    public decimal ControlNumber { get; set; }
}

public class Invoice
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Total { get; set; }
    public ICollection<InvoiceItem> Items { get; set; }
}
```

The total of an item is calculated by either multiplying the `Price` by `Quantity` or `ControlNumber` depending on the item's type. The problem is that I am not sure how to compute the `Total` of the item and then map it when I fetch an invoice using `ProjectTo()`.

In short, I want to have the total of every item autocalculated and then the invoice total to be the sum of those items' totals.

**Approach 1**

I have tried just using a calculated property in the invoice DTO. Something like this:

```
public class InvoiceDto : IMapFrom<Invoice>
{
    public decimal Total 
    { 
        get
        {
             return this.Items.Sum(x => x.Total);
        }
    }

    public ICollection<InvoiceItemDto> Items { get; set; }
}

public class InvoiceItemDto : IMapFrom<InvoiceItem>
{
    public decimal Total { get; set; }

    public void Mapping(Profile profile)
    {
        profile.CreateMap<InvoiceItem, InvoiceItemDto>()
            .ForMember(j => j.Total, opt => opt.MapFrom(x => x.Type == EnumType.SomeType 
                    ? x.Quantiy * x.Price 
                    : x.ControlNumber * x.Price));
    }
}
```

The problem with this method is that I cannot use the `Total` of the invoice in the `Mapping` method. For example if I want to calculate the invoice status in the mapping and this depends on the items' total price, I can't do it because the value in the `Mappings` method is the total of the item in the database (which is 0) and not calculated price inside the `InvoiceItemDto` is not reachable. Also, if I have a `IQueriable` I cannot use the `Total` value of the `InvoiceDto` for sorting for example, because it is a computed property.

**Approach 2**
I have tried adding a computed property inside the item DB entity class. It looks something like this.

```
public class InvoiceItem
{
    private decimal _total;
    public decimal Total
    {
        get
        {
            if (_total == 0)
            {
                _total = this.DistributionType == DistributionType.FixedPrice 
                         ? this.Price * this.Quantity 
                         : this.Price * this.ControlNumber;
            }

            return _total;
        }

        set => _total = value;
    }
}
```

I used the same DTOs as before, just not using a computed property for the `Total` of the `InvoiceDto` but putting it in the `Mapping` method. When I tried this method, the value for the item `Total` was correct if I am fetching a single item using `ItemDto`, but when I fetch invoices with items in them and using `ProjectTo()`, the value was still 0.